# Some really basic questions to do with RESTful and PHP

Tags: php, rest

I am working on a first attempt at a RESTful API. I have designed some simple classes to represent each element of my system including a Message and Room class (it's a chat application with any amount of rooms containing any amount of messages).

I constantly see URIs in the form of, for example

```
/room                                (this would get all rooms)
/room/{room_id}                      (this would create, update or delete a room with this ID)
/room/{room_id}/message              (this would get all messages from a room with the specified ID)
/room/{room_id}/meesage/{message_id} (this would create, update or delete a message with this id)
```

So I guess my two questions are:

1) How do I redirect these requested URIs to my single handling script (located in /api/api.1.0.0.php)

2) How do I request these URIs with the correct HTTP verb like put, delete, update etc.

EDIT: I should add that I am looking to do this without a framework.

Comment: To redirect the request, use mod_rewrite. You can create a rule that just routes all requests under a specific folder/uri back to a single file. From there, your single file can include whatever else it needs.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to use mod_rewrite on apache to redirect all requests to a single script. You will need to use apache and have mod_rewrite installed/setup (it is installed on most shared hosting and is easy to add to a self managed system).

Create a `.htaccess` file in the sub-folder where the API exists under the document root. Add the following to the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?URI=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first condition will make sure the file doesn't exist so you can still load files that do exist (without it, requests for even valid files will rewrite). The second condition does the same but checks that it isn't a valid directory that is being requested. The last line, the rule, captures the URI and tells apache to load `index.php` instead passing the URI to the `URI` get parameter. At the end of the rule are flags, `L` and `QSA`. The `L` flag tells apache to stop processing rules if this one is satisfied and the `QSA` tells apache to automatically append any query string (get string) parameters that were passed.

You can then access the URI in php using `$_GET['URI']`. A simple `$URI = explode('/', $_GET['URI']);` will get you a nicely formatted array of each parameter passed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I seem to be getting an internal server error. My htaccess looks like this: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/api.1.0.php [L,QSA] - I want to redirect the URLs to this script. For example, /api/room/1/message/2 -> that URI gets passed to api/api.1.0.php

Comment: That looks correct. Where is the htaccess file located? If the `/api/` folder exists and all requests are supposed to go through the folder like `/api/request/whatever` then put the htaccess file in there and change the filename to remove the `api/`. Also, you can check your apache error logs to get more detail about what the issue is.

Comment: Ah whoops, I had the api/ when the htaccess was already in the folder. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As for directing to correct part of the app after requesting particular url you should read about routers. All of the major MVC frameworks will have advanced routing solutions. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

If you want to go without framework and use single scripts Apache mod_rewrite is your friend.

For creating requests using different http methods use any of the REST clients like Postman for Chrome.

EDIT:

.htaccess example:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm looking to implement this without a framework.

Comment: So mod_rewrite it is. Simples way would be to create simple routing script that will execute logic in your endpoint/api specific scripts.

You can achieve this by adding .htaccess file in root of your directory: (example in the edited answer)

this fill pass all request to single file, then you can just read the url and include correct files/instantiate correct classes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!